# Concentric circles code will give me one more circle than I input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My concentric circle code works, but when I input the number of circles I need, it will give me one more circle than I want. For example, if I input 7 circles, it will give me 8, but it only does that more over 6 circles. I was wondering what was wrong with my code and why it does that. Thanks.

my code is

```
 if r>=50 or r<=200: #if radius is in range, draw circles
            for c in range (r, 1, int(-r/num_circles)):
                turtle.fillcolor(random.random(),random.random(),\
                random.random()) #circles will be a random color
                turtle.begin_fill()
                turtle.circle(c)
                turtle.penup()
                turtle.left(90) #concentric
                turtle.forward(r/num_circles)
                turtle.right(90)
                turtle.pendown()
                turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.hideturtle()
        time.sleep(5)
        turtle.clear() #clears screen
```

Comment: If you want to make sure that the radius is in between 50 and 200, then use `if r>=50 and r<=200:`. `if r>=50 or r<=200:` means r should be either greater than 50 or less than 200, i.e., `r` can take any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `for` loop `for c in range (r, 1, int(-r/num_circles))` to `for c in range (r, int(r/num_circles), int(-r/num_circles))` so that it can reach to minimum instead of 1.

```
if r>=50 or r<=200: #if radius is in range, draw circles
    for c in range (r, int(r/num_circles), int(-r/num_circles)):
        turtle.fillcolor(random.random(),random.random(),\
        random.random()) #circles will be a random color
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.circle(c)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.left(90) #concentric
        turtle.forward(r/num_circles)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.hideturtle()
    time.sleep(5)
    turtle.clear() #clears screen
```